# Spring Framework main folder is empty

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

hi I'm totally new to the Spring Framework

I'm following tutorials from Youtube and create the Spring project using Maven[image]

I found that in the src directory the main folder is empty
[image]

The App.java is showing at the top src folder instead, why is it so? is it matter? what is the difference between this two directories?

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to build exactly, tell us more so community can help

Comment: Could you provide the link to the exact tutorial you are following? It looks like the folders at the bottom aren't recognized by your IDE as packages.

Answer (score 0):

try to clean and build it using cmd
mvn clean install -U